# MySQL - AFTER INSERT Trigger change another table but mantain one column

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with a creation of a trigger. 
So I have two tables: `product(name,...)` and `detect(id,name_prod,quantity)`, and I wrote a code that whenever you insert a value in `product`, you would create a new row in `detect` for each id existent and initiate the value of quantity to zero:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER detect_default
    AFTER INSERT ON product
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name_prod FROM detect WHERE new.name=name_prod) THEN
                INSERT INTO detect(name_prod,quantity) VALUES(new.name,0);
            END IF;
        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem of this code is that only creates one row in `detect` with the name insert on `product.name` and quantity 0, but the id will be null.

How can I create a row for each existent ID?